# Custom CSS based on If Else Statement from a MySQL query

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, sql

Could someone help me with the following?

I have a basic database of events that each have a specific date_in, time_in, date_out, and time_in that I am trying to display in a html table.  I would like the results  background color to change based on current date/time compared to database date/time of the queried results.

I have figured a rather complex way via MySQL WHERE however this is a lot of redundant coding and I was hoping to find a way to use and IF ELSE statement on the

Here is the solution I found using the MySQL SELECT and WHERE statement however I have several of these statements and it creates a messy set of redundant code.

My conditions are:

If category = "jet" and date_in = $today and result time <= 1 hour from $time ... execute code (query with yellow background)

ElseIf category = "jet" and date_in = $today and result time >= 1 hour from $time ... execute code (query with white background)

Else category = "jet" and date_in != $today ... execute code (query with grey background)

I would then need to do this all over again for 5 additional aircraft categories which creates a lot of redundant code and multiple select statements.

This is only a snippet and I know there are probably really complex ways to do this but this is very basic from a new MySQL/PHP coder.

```
//Gather TIMEZONE, CURRENT TIME, and ACTION TIME 
$set_timezone = date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$today = date('m/d/Y');
$time = date('Hi');


// Build the SELECT statement for JET Aircraft
$select_JETaircraft = "SELECT * FROM aircraft_data WHERE ac_cat = 'Jet' AND (date_in =  '$today' AND time_in <= '$time') ORDER BY time_in ASC"; 
// Run the query
$result = mysql_query($select_JETaircraft);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){    //Creates a loop to loop through results
?>
   <tr class="datacolor_past">
      <td><?php echo "<a href='javascript:delete_aircraft(" . $row['aircraft_id'] . ");'>X</a>"; ?></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><?php echo $row['faa_id']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['ac_type']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['date_in'] . "  -  " . $row['time_in']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['date_out'] . "  -  " . $row{'time_out'}; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['services']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['comments']; } ?></td>
  </tr>
```

A sample of the above can be found [here](http://www.spincreation.com/FBOtracker/index3.php) which is working minus a few bugs around the midnight hour.

I was hoping to come up with a solution similar to this...but I can't get the logic to process.

```
// Build the SELECT statement for JET Aircraft PAST Action Time
$select_JETaircraft = "SELECT * FROM aircraft_data WHERE ac_cat = 'Jet' ORDER BY time_in    ASC"; 

// Run the query
$result = mysql_query($select_JETaircraft);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){    //Creates a loop to loop through results
?>
<tr
         <?php
    $JETdate_in = $row['date_in'];
    $JETtime_in = $row['time_in'];
        if ($JETdate_in = $today)
        {
        echo 'class="datacolor_current"';
        }
        else
        {
        echo 'class="datacolor_past"';
        }
     ?>
     >
     <td><?php echo "<a href='javascript:delete_aircraft(" . $row['aircraft_id'] . ");'>X</a>"; ?></td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td><?php echo $row['faa_id']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['ac_type']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['date_in'] . "  -  " . $row['time_in']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['date_out'] . "  -  " . $row['time_out']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['services']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['comments']; } ?></td>
     </tr>
```

A sample of the above can be found [here](http://www.spincreation.com/FBOtracker/index_test.php) which shows the "JET" code only.  It runs but only shows the class="datacolor_current" regardless of the result of the database query.

Let me know if I need to clarify further...Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need a [CASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html), it basically works as a switch.

Try this:

```
select ac_cat,date_in,result_time,
CASE 
    WHEN ac_cat = 'jet' AND date_in = '2014-03-09' AND result_time <= 1 then 'yellow' 
    WHEN ac_cat = 'jet' AND date_in = '2014-03-09' AND result_time >= 1 then 'white' 
    WHEN ac_cat = 'jet' AND date_in <> '2014-03-09' then 'grey' 
    ELSE 'nocolor'
END as color
from aircraft_data
```

You'll end up with a new column including your custom color.